# VBA - How to loop procedures within the same macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

How to loop procedures?  I don't like "calling" sub because it's too volatile/crash-prone and it flashes my screen... so how to loop procedures within the same macro...?   Example:

```
Sub LoopBase()
      First, Do base
      Then do A
      Then do Base
      Then do B
      Then do Base
      Then do C
      Then do Base
      Then do D
      Then do Base
      Then do procDone
   Exit Sub


Same example, different format....

Sub LoopBase()

procBase:
     Code....

procA:
     Code....
    Goto procBase (and then goto next ProcB)

procB:
     Code....
    Goto procBase (and then goto next ProcC)

procC:
     Code....
    Goto procBase (and then goto next ProcD)

procD:
     Code....
    Goto procBase (and then goto next procDone)

procDone:
     Code...

End Sub
```

Comment: *I don't like "calling" sub because it's too volatile/crash-prone and it flashes my screen* - the problem isn't the calling of procedures, it's the code that's in them, and that will crash and flash regardless of whether you "call" procedures or do everything inline in a single giant scope. For your own sake and that of whoever will inherit and maintain that code in the future, please consider structured programming in actual procedure scopes. `GoTo`-jumping predates procedure scopes, and will only cause grief and headaches.

Comment: That said I've no idea what "how to loop procedures" stands for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to implement flow of code according to your description combining for loop and [select case](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement):

```
Const MaxRunCount = 4

Dim RunCount As Long

For RunCount = 1 To MaxRunCount
    ' insert code "base" here

    Select Case RunCount
    Case 1
        ' put procA here
    Case 2
        ' put procB here
    Case 3
        ' put procC here
    Case 4
        ' put procD here
    End Select
Next RunCount
```

> I don't like "calling" sub because it's too volatile/crash-prone and it flashes my screen

As commented already, it's not due to calling a sub, but what it contains, so my solution my not solve your problem at the end.

Comment: Fantastic answer!  I will implement.  My current code has 170 lines!  This will shorten down to about 100 lines.  Awesome!!  Thanks again!!